# OSX Sonoma /etc/hosts and local dev

Tags: networking, macos, mac, dns

I have setup a VirtualBox with CentOs as a guest for local web development.
I usually edit the /etc/hosts file to direct domain to the local environment in the guest. This worked totally fine until yesterday.

Since upgrading my MacBook from BigSur to Sonoma (14), I experience following issue:

Any browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge) gives me a Connection refused error when trying to connect to a local website for development, hosted in the very guest.
When entering an ip adrress, everything works fine. (e.g. 192.168.178.x)

So, I figured it must a be a dns issue with OSX Sonoma.
Known tricks like dns flush, re-creating hosts file, rebooting, ONYXing the complete system does not help. Also explicit clearing of the very browser caches does not help.
Firewall on/off does not have an effect.

What do I do wrong?
What can be done to establish the dns resolving of local dev domains?

Many thanks for help in advance
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I solved it by adding --host '0.0.0.0' to the ng serve command:

```
ng serve --host '0.0.0.0' --disable-host-check
```

After this I could access dev domains declared in the hosts file again.

Hope it helps!